# update devexpress project's version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, devexpress

I have many errors after updating my project from [devexpress 16](https://www.devexpress.com/) to [devexpress 21](https://www.devexpress.com/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Make sure that the target framework version of your product is .NET Framework 4.5.2+. Then upgrade your projects using the [Project Converter tool](https://docs.devexpress.com/ProjectConverter/2529/project-converter), available within the DevExpress .NET installation.

P.S. Please refer to the [Upgrade Notes](https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/2221/installation/upgrade-notes) documentation article to learn how to upgrade your projects from one version of our controls to another.